# How to convert the tensor model into an onnx file

Tags: onnx, tensorrt

I have a tensorrt engine file, a builder in jetson nx2. But my onnx file is missing. How to convert the tensor model to onnx file?

e.g: `a.engine` file -> `a.onnx`

Please give me a suggestion thanks

All I retrieved from the search engine are from onnx to tensor model.

Answer (score 0):

You will need **Python 3.7-3.10**,

1. Install **tf2onnx** using pip
   `pip install -U tf2onnx`
2. use to following command. You will need to provide the following:

- the path to your TensorFlow model (where the model is in **saved model** format)
- a name for the ONNX output file

`python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model tensorflow-model-path --output model.onnx`

The above command uses a default of 13 for the ONNX opset. If you need a newer opset, or want to limit your model to use an older opset then you can provide the --opset argument to the command.

`python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model tensorflow-model-path --opset 17 --output model.onnx`

3. For checkpoint format:

`python -m tf2onnx.convert --checkpoint  tensorflow-model-meta-file-path --output model.onnx --inputs input0:0,input1:0 --outputs output0:0`

Follow the official **tf2onxx** repository to learn more: https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx